# Rails - migrate from hstore to jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use Postgresql. I tried the following migration to cast a field from hstore to jsonb in Rails.

```
change_column :table_name, :field_name, 'jsonb USING CAST(field_name AS jsonb)'
```

I get the following exception:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  **default for column** "field_name" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb.

Comment: try add `default: ''` to your migration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just figured out the issue. The exception clearly states that there is a default value which it is not able to automatically cast.

There was a default value for the column which I tried to cast.

Changing to the following migration worked.

```
change_column_default :table_name, :field_name, nil
change_column :table_name, :field_name, 'jsonb USING CAST(field_name AS jsonb)'
```